# apparently correct rscript does not plot curve in ggplot 2

Tags: r, ggplot2, curve-fitting

I have tried different script options from other related questions but none seems to plot the desired curve, despite the script looks correct and runs...
https://www.dropbox.com/s/efxbx6qh4z32snx/examplecurve.csv?dl=0

```
d=read.csv("examplecurve.csv")
require(nlme)
model <- nls(y ~ a*(x^b),start = list(a = exp(coef(m)[1]), b = 
coef(m)[2]),  data = d)
summary(model)
fontsize=12
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
geom_point(col="black", fill = "grey",alpha=0.8, shape=21, size = 2) +
stat_smooth(method = "nls", 
        method.args = list(formula = y ~ a*(x^b),
    method.args = list(formula = y ~ a*(x^b), 
    start = list(coef(model))),
    se = F, size = 0.5, data = d))+
                        
   theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='transparent', 
 colour='black'),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_text(colour="black", size=fontsize),
    axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5,colour="black", 
 size=fontsize),
    axis.title.y = element_text(colour="black", size=fontsize),
    axis.text.y  = element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5,colour="black", 
 size=fontsize)
 )+  theme(legend.position="none",
        legend.justification=c(1,1),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 12))
```

I would also like to add error ribbons...

T
hanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from [this previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72746165/issues-connected-to-creating-a-nls-model-in-r/72746496#72746496), you can add an error ribbon around an `nls` fit using these little functions:

```r
nls_se <- function(formula, data, start, ...) {
  mod <- nls(formula, data, start)
  class(mod) <- "nls_se"
  mod
}

predict.nls_se <- function(model, newdata, level = 0.9, ...) {
  class(model) <- "nls"
  p <- investr::predFit(model, newdata = newdata, 
                        interval = "confidence", level = level)
  list(fit = p, se.fit = p[,3] - p[,1])
}
```

These allow you to use `geom_smooth` directly with your target formula:

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(col="black", fill = "grey",alpha = 0.8, shape = 21, size = 2) +
  geom_smooth(method = nls_se, formula = y ~ a * x^b,
              method.args = list(start = list(a = 1, b = 1)))
```

[image]

Or, with some styling choices (thanks Rui Barradas)

```r
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point(col="black", fill = "grey",alpha = 0.8, shape = 21, size = 2) +
  geom_smooth(method = nls_se, formula = y ~ a * x^b,
              method.args = list(start = list(a = 1, b = 1)),
              color = "navy", fill = "deepskyblue4", alpha = 0.2,
              linetype = 2, linewidth = 0.4) +
  theme_Agus_camacho(20)
```

[image]

Comment: nope, after loading your functions, executing this exact script did not plot any curve nor ribbon, in my case.

Comment: @Aguscamacho that's odd. It clearly works otherwise I wouldn't have been able to generate the above images. Did you get an error or warning? Do you have the `investr` package installed?

Comment: I do have it and running. Here are the errors: Error in `geom_point()`:
! Problem while computing aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data
  (100)
✖ Fix the following mappings: `x`
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: and rlang gives: Backtrace:
  1. base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5. ggplot2:::by_layer(...)
 12. ggplot2 (local) f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
 13. l$compute_aesthetics(d, plot)
 14. ggplot2 (local) compute_aesthetics(..., self = self)
 15. ggplot2:::check_aesthetics(evaled, n)

Comment: @Aguscamacho can you check your data to ensure that the columns are called `x` and `y`, and that you don't have any global variables called x and y. The error is coming from the first layer, (geom_point), which has nothing to do with my code at all

Comment: Your code works indeed with the csv I sent, but not with the dataset the csv was directly derived from, yikes!. I`ll find a way to make it work. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is no model `m` created in the question so I fitted a OLS model to have the rest of the code work. As it turned out, it wasn't a bad choice.

Don't put the `formula` in the `method.args` list, `formula` is a `stat_smooth` argument and it's better to have it where it is expected to be.

I have created a custom `theme` with your settings (code at the end) in order not to distract from the main problem. Note that `fontsize` is passed as an argument to the custom theme.

```r
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)

fontsize <- 12

m <- lm(y ~ x, d)
model <- nls(y ~ a*(x^b),start = list(a = exp(coef(m)[1]), 
                                      b = coef(m)[2]),  data = d)

ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(col="black", fill = "grey",alpha=0.8, shape=21, size = 2) +
  stat_smooth(method = "nls", 
              formula = y ~ a * x^b,
              method.args = list(start = list(a = exp(coef(m)[1]), 
                                              b = coef(m)[2])),
              se = FALSE, linewidth = 0.5) +
  theme_Agus_camacho(fontsize)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Custom `theme`

```r
theme_Agus_camacho <- function(fontsize){ 
  theme_minimal(base_size = fontsize) %+replace%
    theme(
      panel.background = element_rect(fill='transparent', 
                                      colour='black'),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      axis.title.x = element_text(colour="black", size=fontsize),
      axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5,colour="black", 
                                  size=fontsize),
      axis.title.y = element_text(colour="black", size=fontsize),
      axis.text.y  = element_text(angle=0, vjust=0.5,colour="black", 
                                  size = fontsize),
      legend.position="none",
      legend.justification=c(1,1),
      legend.key = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'),
      legend.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent'),
      legend.text = element_text(size = fontsize)
    )
}
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks heaps for your complementary answers! The detail of showing how to make a personalized theme was lovely!

Comment: it was interesting that your script plots the curve only if I keep the se parameter as FALSE.

Comment: @Aguscamacho That happens because the `predict.nls` method does not output lower and upper CI limits.